# How to get Spotify authentication open in new tab or pop up window

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I need the information that is in my url, however when I need to authenticate spotify it opens it in the same tab that the app is working, is there a way to change which tab it opens in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url, new=2)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html):

> Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible. If autoraise is True, the window is raised if possible (note that under many window managers this will occur regardless of the setting of this variable).

ps. `webbrowser` is a python library